# Display Another Variable Inside a CFOUTPUT

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a note pushing to people that is Long Text format.
So that display is:

```
 <cfoutput>
 #maindata#
 </cfoutput>
```

And lets say that data is a bunch of "blah blah blah, and more text data, blah blah" which is outputting properly.

What I am trying to do, is add an additional variable note inside the "LongText"

So in the text data I have tried.

```
  #set.newnote#
```

I have tried these 2 with no luck either:

```
 #Variables[set.newnote]#
 #evaluate(set.newnote)#
```

I'm not having luck.  Is this possible or do I need to break out of the output to add an additional output after.

Comment: What do you mean by `add an additional variable note inside the "LongText"`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're asking this because you want to nest coldfusion string variables inside text stored in a database.

You could do this using a combination of `evaluate()` and `de()` like this:

```
<cfset mockDBText = "The ##x.a## jumps over the ##x.b##." />
<!--- the double ## above is just for escaping a single # - in your DB you would not need ## --->
<cfoutput>#mockDBText#</cfoutput>
<cfset x.a = "quick brown fox" />
<cfset x.b = "lazy dog" />
<cfoutput><br /> #evaluate(de(mockDBText))#</cfoutput>
```

...however beware the huge security risks of doing this with any text derived from user input - explained in more detail for example here: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3861-evaluating-database-records-that-contain-coldfusion-interpolation-expressions-in-adobe-coldfusion-2018.htm

A safer way is to include your own tokens to delimit variables inside DB text, and then use a function to parse these and only output known safe variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>
mainData = "blah blah blah";
moreData = "more more more";
writeOutput(mainData & moreData);
</cfscript>
```

or

```
<cfoutput>#mainData##moreData#</cfoutput>
```

or if you want to insert moreData into mainData:

```
<cfscript>
newString = Left(mainData, 1, 5) & moreData & Right(mainData, 6, Len(mainData)-5));
writeOutput(newString);
</cfscript>
```

And another note... never ever ever ever use `Evaluate(nonSanitizedUserText)` or you will open your application up to injection attacks.

Comment: There is no need to do string concatenation in the second example, you can also do `<cfoutput>#maindata# #moreData#</cfoutrput>`

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I have it fixed with just a seperate output.  But it isn't really that.  It is pulling the text data from the database "Long Text Type".  And in that data I am trying to put in the additional #moredata# which comes from that database pull of text.  It does not display the variable string but just the #moredata# as text.  I don't think I can do it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Long text type will be treated by CF the same way as any text. You wrote: What I am trying to do, is add an additional variable note inside the "LongText"... this tells me you need to create a new string... so maybe you need to use a combination of string functions to create your new string?